# unable to install the desired spacy version ==2.0.18 on kaggle

Tags: python-3.x, pip, spacy, kaggle

I want to uninstall the existing spacy in kaggle which kaggle by default download for us which is spacy == 2.1.3 but I want to install version==2.0.18

```
!pip uninstall spacy==2.1.3
```

but I got stock here

```
Uninstalling spacy-2.0.18:
  Would remove:
    /opt/conda/bin/spacy
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy-2.0.18.dist-info/*
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

But I am not able to type y/n on the kaggle notebook as it is not control prompt.
So how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Say "yes" in the command line:

```
!pip uninstall -y spacy
```

Comment: Add option `-y` or `--yes` like in the answer.